# Как обратиться к последнему элементу mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Я хотел бы обратиться к последнему элементу в цикле `while`, чтобы не добавлять табуляцию в коде. Я бы мог сделать ещё один запрос к БД(на длину таблицы), но я бы хотел понять, как это сделать без лишнего запроса к БД
Сейчас это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы хотел последнему элементу задать только `\n` и не добавлять табуляцию, чтобы `</ul>` был без табуляции

```php
<?php 

$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'news');

if (connection == false) {
    echo 'Не удалось подключиться к базе данных';
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles_categories`");

?>

<ul>
    <?php
        while (($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
            $stroke = '<li>' . $record['title'] . '</li>';
            echo $stroke . "\n\t";
        }
    ?>
</ul>

<?php
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Какой в этом глубокий смысл?

Comment: @u_mulder понять, можно ли такое делать

Comment: `trim($str, "\t");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл решение. Я не делаю ещё один запрос `mysqli_query`, а с помощью `mysqli_num_rows` получаю количество записей, которые я получил с помощью `mysqli_query`

```php
<?php 

$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'news');

if (connection == false) {
    echo 'Не удалось подключиться к базе данных';
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles_categories`");
$resultLength = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>

<ul>
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        while (($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
            $i++;
            $stroke = '<li>' . $record['title'] . '</li>';
            $stroke = $i === $resultLength ? $stroke .= "\n" : $stroke .= "\n\t";
            echo $stroke;
        }
    ?>
</ul>

<?php
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```